# Vue and Vue-tippy html content

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I need to show an html content inside `vue-tippy` element (https://github.com/KABBOUCHI/vue-tippy) with data-binding elements, but it not works,

```
<div id="demo">
    <p>{{message}}</p>
    <br />
    <input v-model="message" title="Input">
    <br />
    Default example (it works)
    <button title="Hi!" v-tippy> My Button! </button>
    <br />
    Data binding example (it not works)
    <button title="{{ message }} " v-tippy> {{ message }} </button>
    <br />
    Data binding example (it works)
    <button :title="message" v-tippy> {{ message }} </button>

    <br />
    Data binding example  html content (it not works)
    <button id="button3" v-tippy data-html="#contentpopup"> {{ message }} -  html content </button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="contentpopup" style="background:red;">
      <div>
         {{ message }} - My html content
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
</div>
```

JS

```
var vueTippy = require('vue-tippy')
Vue.use(vueTippy)

var data = {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
}

var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: data
})
```

how can i fix this?

thanks

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: No, on hover v-tippy show "{{ message }} - My html content" instead "Hello Vue.js!- My html content"

Comment: But that is your HTML content... Oh, you want the binding to happen in that popup also? What if you move the `#contentpopup` div before the `button` definition?

Comment: yes, but i need to render value inside html content {{ message }} should be Hello Vue.js!

Comment: No, doesn't work anyway

Comment: What is that exactly you want?

Comment: @VAMSIKRISHNA i need to render vue data inside v-tippy html content

Comment: @AldoZumaran what is inside v-tippy html content?

Comment: tooltip html content

Comment: I think the problem is that `v-tippy` is just a bad port of `tippy.js` for `vue`, which didn't take this into account and most probably is an issue with the library itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added support for HTML Template and Vue Component.

Update vue-tippy package to the latest and your code will work.

Example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.btn {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 10px 36px -4px rgba(77, 96, 232, 0.3);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, #73a5ff, #5477f5);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #73a5ff, #5477f5);
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  font-family: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.25;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.0/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kabbouchi.com/vue-tippy/vue-tippy.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button class="btn" v-tippy data-distance="15" data-theme="light" data-animation="scale" data-arrowsize="big" data-trigger="click" data-interactive="true" data-animatefill="false" data-arrow="true" data-html="#contentpopup">
    Popover HTML <small class="opacity-low">(click)</small>
  </button>
  <div id="contentpopup" style="display: none">
    <div>
      <h3> Header</h3>
      <p style="color: black"> {{ message }} - data binding </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: does not work even here